# Calculate and display Best Seller?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm wondering if anybody knows a solution before i start trying and failing for a few hours...

I have a table of all my orders since March, which includes the value of the orders, the date the order was placed, and the salesman for the order.

I'd like to use a cell to calculate who is the highest Salesman for the month, by looking at all sales by eash Salesman, making a sum of the total value within the dates specified, and presenting the Salesman with the highest total.

I'm ready for the eventuality that the solution is to calculate these values into another table first, and then run the formula from that table. However i'd really like all my statistics to be drawn from just one source table, so each month i can just dump the latest info and not have to worry.

[image]

Comment: One way to do it: select your range and go to Insert, then use PivotChart & PivotTable and filter by needs. When you enter new data just Refresh and your chart/table is updated with the new info.

Comment: I can probably put together a user defined formula, or a subroutine, to solve this if you are interested in a VBA solution. Let me know if you are.

Comment: You can do this with `SUMIFS` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A10,MATCH(MAX((E2=MONTH(B2:B10))*$C$2:$C$10),IF(E2=MONTH(B2:B10),$C$2:$C$10),))
```

[image]

Comment: Lee, it looks like your formula will find the maximum value for the month, but it does not sum all of the inputs - so if Salesman A totals more small sales in the month than Salesman B, B still gets selected because he had a single large sale. I cannot work the formula out myself.

Comment: @JustinDoward Currently i am using a separate table of values per Salesman that first SUMS their total for the month (or actually week in my live case), and then my main table pulls the top seller from there. I may have to look into using a Pivot instead, as the method i'm using breaks my references when i replace my list of salesman with the latest list.